Foundry - How to fuzz struct array with specific length assumption
Assume that I have the following struct and function in my contract:
struct MyStruct {
   uint256 num1;
   uint256 num2;
   address[] addresses;
}


MyStruct[] public str;

function updateMyStruct(MyStruct[] memory _str) public {
  str = _str;
}

Assume that I wanna test this contract now in foundry and also want to use fuzzing.
My Goal is to have a fuzz parameter as MyStruct[] directly, because otherwise, I'd need to construct this whole MyStruct[] myself which is not good since it just makes code look ugly (Note that there're other arrays inside MyStruct, so imagine constructing each one of them)
For most of my tests, I really need MyStruct[] to be size of 2 and not only that, Mystruct[0].addresses.length and MyStruct[1].addresses.length both have to be 3.
At first glance, I thought to use vm.assume:
 function test_WhenProposalIsCreated(MyStruct[] memory _str) external {
   vm.assume(_str.length == 2);
   vm.assume(_str[0].addresses.length == 3);
   vm.assume(_str[1].addresses.length == 3);
 }

This has a serious downside and takes huge amount of time for obvious reasons which I understand.
Then, I tried to have(note the [2]):
function test_WhenProposalIsCreated(MyStruct[2] memory _str) external {

I still need to not allow .addresses.length to be other than 3. How would I achieve this ? vm.assume clearly takes so much time, it's not worth it and creating this struct array in the tests itself is also not good - even if you say to create it in setUp, that's not good as there're variables in the struct that I need fuzzed in each test.
Any thoughts ?
